# How to autoref an appendix in IEEE template

Tags: appendices, ieeetran, ieee-style, ieeeconf, autoref

I need to autoref an appendix but I need the autoref to appear as `Appendix A` not `section A`. I use an IEEE conference template. It has a specific command for appendices and to add appendices under it, it uses \section command. Here is my minimal script to illustrate the issue:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{Title Here}    
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        Abstract here.
    \end{abstract}
    
    \section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}
    Some text here. See this (\autoref{app:cc}). I want it to appear as Appendix but it appears as section. 
    \clearpage
    \appendices
    \section{Title(1) here}\label{app:cc}
    Some text here.

    
\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

**EDIT:**

Please note that I do not want to override the section command with appendix. I use `autoref` to sections in other places.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is due to `IEEEtran` using `\appendices` rather than the more commonly used `\appendix`.

Hopefully someone can offer a better solution but in the mean time I have a hacky solution... I've made a new command for referencing appendices, that offers the same output as if `\autoref` could detect the `\appendices` section properly.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\refappendix}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{Appendix~\ref*{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\title{Title Here}  
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
        Abstract here.
    \end{abstract}

    \section{Introduction}\label{sec:intro}
    Some text here. See this (\refappendix{app:cc}). I want it to appear as Appendix but it appears as section.
    \clearpage

    \appendices
    \section{Title(1) here} \label{app:cc}
    Some text here.

\end{document}
```